# Java Keystroke catchining directional keys

Tags: java

I am catching keys for bindings, so far most characters work fine, until I reached the directional keys (up down left right)

My code for catching other keys are:

```
KeyStroke key_3 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("3");
```

How do I catch the directional keys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP")
```

and you can specify the ctrl and shift versions with

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control UP")
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift UP"
```